# HashMap Object key

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, key

In Java, I have a class:

```
public static class Key {

    int[] vector = null;

    private int hashcode = 0;

    Key (int[] key) {
        vector = new int[key.length];
        // here is the problem
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, vector, 0, key.length);
    }

    public int hashCode() { ... }

    public boolean equals(Object o) { ... }

}
```

which acts as a key in the `HashMap<Key, int[]> map`. In code I do:

```
// value int[] array is filled before
map.put(new Key(new int[] {5, 7}), value);
```

But this creates an argument array `{5, 7}` twice - first time when `Key` constructor is called and then inside that constructor.

I can not use `HashMap<int[], int[]> map` because then it is not clear what `hashCode` will be used for `int[]`. So I wrap up the `int[]` key inside `Key` class.

How is it possible to create an argument array (which can be of different size) just once?

I do not like this solution:

```
map.put(new Key(5, 7), value);

// and rewrite the constructor
Key (int a1, int a2) {
    vector = new int[2];
    vector[0] = a1;
    vector[1] = a2;
}
```

because generally an argument array can be of various size.

Comment: why you can not assign array to vector member? like this Key(int[] keys) { this.vector = keys; } The disadvantage of solution is key values can be modified from outside of this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it possible to create an argument array (which can be of different size) just once?

Unfortunately, you cannot do that, because there is no way to make a built-in Java array immutable. If it were possible to make immutable arrays, the following would work:

```
Key (int[] key) {
    // Do not do this!!!
    vector = key;
}
```

Although the above would work in fully cooperative environments, hostile users could pass an array, and let the key calculate the hash, and then change array elements to introduce errors into your code. That's why you are absolutely right when you decided to copy the array passed in.

You can change the function to accept variable number of arguments, like this:

```
Key (int ... key) {
    vector = new int[key.length];
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, vector, 0, key.length);
}
```

This would let you create arrays implicitly rather than explicitly:

```
map.put(new Key(5, 7), value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) for the parameter and use [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29):

```
Key (int... key) {
    vector = Arrays.copyOf(key, key.length);
}
```

Now you can call the constructor with any number if int parameters (including no parameters) and it won't cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since `arraycopy` is being used to do a deep copy from one object to another, at some point you need to create two objects where the second is the same size as the argument array. So `vector = new int[key.length];` looks correct.

Btw, when I compile your code I get an error that `static` is not a valid modifier for class, only `public`, `abstract`, or `final` are.